# Fpdf- how to arrange elements in left and right corner

Tags: php, html, fpdf

I'm trying to generate a dynamic pdf during php form submission and with the form contents using fpdf. it worked. but now i don't know how to arrange the elements. the result pdf format is :

```
                               Results

 _____________________________________________________________________________________
 _____________________________________________________________________________________

 Name: xyz                                           Age/Sex: 28/F ; Date: 22/09/2014
 Report No:36                                        Email: xyz@gmail.com
                                                     Mob: 9999999999

 ______________________________________________________________________________________

   Class: Some Text from form

 ______________________________________________________________________________________

   Interpretation: Some Text from form

 ______________________________________________________________________________________

   Comments: Some Text from form



                                                                Name: xyz
                                                                Signature:
```

I tried this much:

```
$pdf=new PDF_HTML();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 15);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);
$pdf->Cell( 0, 15, 'Results', 0, 0, 'C' );
$pdf->Ln(5);
$pdf->Line(10, 20, 210-10, 20);
$pdf->Line(10, 20, 210-10, 20);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',7); 
$pdf->Cell( 0, 29, 'Name :', 0, 0, 'L',0);
$pdf->write(2,$_POST['name']);
$pdf->Cell( 0, 29, 'Email :', 0, 0, 'R',0);
$pdf->write(2,$_POST['email']);
$pdf->Output();
```

But this isn't worked. can any one please help me how to use this. this is the first time i'm using fpdf and i searched a lot in Google but didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try This...
[php.net/manual/en/pdf.examples-basic.php](http://php.net/manual/en/pdf.examples-basic.php)

```
<?php
$p = PDF_new();

/*  open new PDF file; insert a file name to create the PDF on disk */
if (PDF_begin_document($p, "", "") == 0) {
    die("Error: " . PDF_get_errmsg($p));
}

PDF_set_info($p, "Creator", "hello.php");
PDF_set_info($p, "Author", "Rainer Schaaf");
PDF_set_info($p, "Title", "Hello world (PHP)!");

PDF_begin_page_ext($p, 595, 842, "");

$font = PDF_load_font($p, "Helvetica-Bold", "winansi", "");

PDF_setfont($p, $font, 24.0);
PDF_set_text_pos($p, 50, 700);
PDF_show($p, "Hello world!");
PDF_continue_text($p, "(says PHP)");
PDF_end_page_ext($p, "");

PDF_end_document($p, "");

$buf = PDF_get_buffer($p);
$len = strlen($buf);

header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Length: $len");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=hello.pdf");
print $buf;

PDF_delete($p);
?>
```

Comment: Hi edcoder thanks for a quick response. can u please tell me how could i use this code in my program. because i tried it as a separate file program but didn't worked..